# Unbind all events from the content that is added dynamically via AJAX

Tags: jquery, events, asynchronous, unbind

**Please read this part first**:
Turns out my problem was that someone used `onclick="some javascript"`, which all my event stoppers didn't catch.

I didn't find any information on this topic, should this be a community wiki post?

---

I have content which has dynamically loaded content, where I want to unbind events:

Code example *on init*:

```
<div id="Wrap"></div>
```

Code example *after loading content via AJAX*:

```
<div id="Wrap">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

**What I want:**

- The `.item` can have any event
- The item is dynamically loaded via AJAX
- It has to unbind all events, and replace it with one (<- this is no problem)

**What I have**:

```
$(document).ready( handleWriteDisableds ); 

$(window).load( handleWriteDisableds ); // in doc ready

$( document ).ajaxComplete( handleWriteDisableds );


function handleWriteDisableds(){
    $('.item').unbind() // remove all events set in doc-ready

    $(document).on('click', '.item', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();  // prevent default behaviour
        e.stopPropagation(); // Don't bubble up
        alert('no can do');
        return false; // hardcore stopping stuff
    }); 
}
```

**What I need:**
To unbind EVERYTHING after it dynamically loads.

**Edit** Oh, Turns out we have someone who used the onclick attribute, those don't get stopped apparently. I'll update if I have more info

Comment: so what's the problem? aren't you able to unbind all the events?

Comment: If you're using delegation, you need to unbind the parent element that you set the delegation on.

Comment: I've added a little more code to my example. The events dont unbind

Comment: add code where you load dynamic content ?

Comment: When '.item' are added to the dom, they don't come bundled with events. They are just added to the dom. Click them, nothing happens. You don't need to unbind events, because there are no events bond to them. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

Try jQuery off() function to remove the event attached to the dynamically added element. [jQuery off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

add this in the ajax success callback.

```
   $('.item').off(); // with no arguments removes all handlers attached to the elements.
```

Comment: What I don't understand is, why would he need to remove events just at the beginning, when the document is ready, when no events have been bond at all yet?

Comment: And off is about the same as unbind ;)

Answer (score 2):

Try this. It might help you with this quick fix. It will unbind all the events.

---

**EDIT:**

Dynamically added items won't have the handler - i.e, in your case the newly added DOM having ".item" won't work unless you rebind the handler. So, if you are adding contents dynamically(via AJAX) then how your dynamic content gets a handler attached with it?

You need to figure it out how it gets handler for dynamic contents.

By default the dynamically added content don't have any handler bind to it.

---

```js
$(function() {

  $(document).on('click', '.item', function(e) {
    e.unbind();
    alert('no can do')
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Wrap">
  <div class="item">Dynamic Content 1</div>
  <div class="item">Dynamic Content 2</div>
  <div class="item">Dynamic Content 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: +1, This is a technique I havent though about, nice. I believe my problem lies somewhere else, I'll update my answer